# When login button is clicked the page is Redirecting but not rendering the page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In user login form I am when I click login button it gives a token.
I am setting up the token in local storage and redirecting to 'customers' page.The page gets redirected to 'customers' but the page is not rendered.I have added a console.log in customer Page to check the whether the page is rendering or not.In this case it is not rendering it.

LoginForm

```
import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import axios from '../config/Axios';


class LoginForm extends React.Component {

constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
            error: '',
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

handleChange(e) {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        const loginData = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
        }

        axios.post('/users/login', loginData, {
            headers: {
                'x-auth': localStorage.getItem('token')
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response.data)
                if (response.data.error) {
                    const error = response.data.error
                    this.setState({ error })
                }
                else {
                    const token = response.data.token
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                    this.props.history.push('/customers')
                }
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="form-group container">
                <h1>Login</h1>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="email-login">Email</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} name="email" id="email-login" />
                    <br />
                    <label htmlFor="password-login">Password</label>
                    <br />
                    <input type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} name="password" id="password-login" />
                    <br />
                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-info">Login</button>
                    {
                        !_.isEmpty(this.state.error) && <h3>{this.state.error}</h3>
                    }
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default LoginForm
```

Customer Page

```
class CustomerList extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            customers: [],
            isLoading: true,
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/customers', {
            headers: {
                'x-auth': localStorage.getItem('token')
            }
        })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response.data)
                const customers = response.data
                this.setState({ customers, isLoading: false })
                return customers
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    handleChange(text) {
        console.log(this.state.customers)
        const customerDatas = this.state.customers
        const customers = customerDatas.filter((customerData => {
            return customerData.name.toLowerCase().includes(text)
        }))

        if (this.state.customers.length) {
            this.setState({ customers })
        }
        else {
            console.log(`${customers}......`)
            this.componentDidMount()
        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log('customer localStorage', localStorage)
        return (
            <div>
                <br />
                <SearchBox handleChange={this.handleChange} />
                <br />
                {this.state.isLoading ? (
                    <Loader />
                ) : (
                        <div>
                            <h3>Progress Bar</h3>
                        </div>
                    )}
                <br />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default CustomerList
```

Comment: can you print this.props.history in your LoginCOmponent and let me know that it is not undefined?

Comment: It is not undefined it return an object {length: 50, action: "POP", location: {…}, createHref: ƒ, push: ƒ, …}

Comment: ok have you tried console.log in your render method in CustomerList Component? is it getting printed?

Comment: I have done console.log it is redirecting to the link but not rendering it .

Comment: If it prints "customer localStorage" in the console then it means that it is actually rendering it

Comment: yes but it is not printing it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198240/discussion-between-lone-wolf-and-biswajeet-gope).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in chat and comments - you did not have router added in your Router Component
Please add the below line

```
<Route path='/customers' exact={true} component={CustomerList} />
```

Answer (score 0):

check what the this.props what will be shown is that     content history or not  undefined
and do you have a router to element